# Hide Kendo UI grid toobar

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How can I hide the toolbar (pager) for the KendoUI grid?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
     dataBound: function() {
    $("#grid .k-grid-pager").css('display','none');
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display `pageSize` number of records but do not have pagination then simply define `pageSize` in the dataSource but `pageable` as false in the grid definition:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    ...
    pageable: false
});
```